# Electron Notifications - Custom Windows Notification Audio

Tags: windows, notifications, electron

According to the Electron Docs[https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/notification#playing-sounds] it is possible to play custom sounds through MacOS when displaying notifications. I've got that working pretty well. However, when working with windows, custom sounds don't seem to work the same. After searching the internet for a while, I've found no definitive solution for playing custom audio when toast notifications are shown.

It seems like this should be possible. Slack does this well. My only thought is that slack is doing something along the lines of... when the notification shows, they ultimately have the render process play the sound through a regular `new Audio(...).play()`.

The downside of any non native solution is that you may end up not properly adhering to how the user has setup OS level notifications.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.